# RADEditor in Sitefinity 10.1.6500.x removes mailto links upon save

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity, radeditor

In Sitefinity 10.1.65xx.x (including 10.1.6523.0), the RADEditor removes `mailto:` links from a dynamic content when you save it.

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Create a new project using **Sitefinity Project Manager** for Sitefinity `10.1.6500.0` or `10.1.6502.0` or `10.1.6523.0`.
2. Login in to the backend GUI and go to `Content > News` and create a new news post.
3. Type some text and select it and choose the `Insert Link` button.
4. Choose the type of link as `Email` Link and give some email address there and insert it.
5. If you switch to HTML view now, you can see the tag as something like `<a href="mailto:<whatever-email-given>">Text</a>`.
6. Click the `Save as Draft` button.

You should see that the contents have changed to `<a>Text</a>`. Essentially the `mailto:` is stripped off.

Normal links work perfectly fine. And this happens in all dynamic content types like **News**, **Blog**, etc. The **Content Block widgets don't have this issue**.

What is going on here? Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Could not reproduce it neither in News nor in a custom dynamic module.

Can you try in another browser, maybe in Private mode so that no additional extensions are loaded

Comment: @VeselinVasilev I tried in private mode in Edge, Firefox and Chrome. All reproduce the issue consistently and across machines. The app is running on Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5 (dev machine Windows 10 1703 (build 15063.608) with IIS Express), if that helps.

Comment: Same here @RajshriMohanKS, could not replicate it. The mail to links work fine for me on 10.1.6523.0. I think your javascript might be stripping it off, try disabling all of your javascript and test again

Comment: @AmitJoshi Can you tell me which database were you using? I suspect that may be the problem since it occurs only when I hit **Save to Draft** or **Publish**...

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS It's just a standard IIS setup with SQL Dev 2016. I also checked this in Azure but couldn't replicate it either.

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS Can you go to Administration -> Settings -> Advanced -> Appearance -> "Rad Editor's content filters" and remove the value? Let me know if that helps

Comment: @AmitJoshi I'm using SQL Dev 2016 too. And no, I've already tried the **Rad Editors Content Filters** setting and did it once again since you mentioned, they don't help. This is how the problem looks like, if it helps: https://imgur.com/a/qWXOk The top image is how the content looks before pressing **Save Draft** and how it becomes after pressing **Save Draft**

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS, Are you using the link feature in the the WYSIWYG or manually coding the links?

Comment: @JonR. I've tried both. Both have the same results. However, if I code the link manually in the DB, the results show up as expected (With `mailto:` working properly). But if I use the editor to save the content, it doesn't work.

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS I was able to reproduce this issue on a fresh install of 10.1.6524, I used the package manager to install 10.1.6500 then nuget to upgrade to the latest internal 10.1.6524. I am also using SQL 2016 DEV edition. I believe you are correct is stating it is a database issue.

Comment: @JonR. Apparently, it isn't the database. We raised the issue in Sitefinity forums and after months of hope in vain, one Mr. James has found the solution: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Shared-Content-Block-and-Long-Text-Field-filters-HTML-even-after-setting-RadEditor-filters-to-None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We raised the issue in Sitefinity's forums and this is what ensued:

http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/radeditor-in-sitefinity-10-1-6500-x-removes-mailto-links-upon-save#HlbQHcE3622pWP8AAERlJg

Apparently, a new **Data Processing Framework** layer is introduced in Sitefinity in `10.1.xxxx.x` that is breaking Sitefinity's own functionality. I've no idea why a majority of the people weren't able to replicate the issue. But the solution involves extending the default XSS Sanitizer and adding the `tel:` and `mailto:` protocols to the default whitelist. The answer is described in detail here: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Shared-Content-Block-and-Long-Text-Field-filters-HTML-even-after-setting-RadEditor-filters-to-None